# Have I fitted my water cooler correctly?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

This is my first time water cooling a CPU, so I don't know if the temperatures I'm seeing are bad or reasonable.

I've got an AMD Threadripper 3970x with a Corsair iCUE H115i PRO XT.

I'm running the CPU at about 35% load. The CPU temperature is around 78c (which seems really hot, for the CPU load) and the coolant temperature is around 32.5c, ambient temperature is around 20c. Figures taken from the iCUE dashboard.

This doesn't seem right to me. I expected the coolant temperature to be higher,as its cooling a hot CPU and the CPU to be running cooler as its not under a particularly heavy load, and should be well cooled by the water cooler.

Are these temperatures reasonable? or might I have fitted the cooler incorrectly?
What can I check to make sure the cooler is fitted correctly.

Comment: You can't really install the cooler improperly without damaging the socket.  So it's likely the thermal paste that is the problem.

Comment: Modern CPUs have a turbo feature which increases the CPU frequency in case not all cores are used. Therefore "only 35% load" does not imply that the CPU does run at 35% power usage.

Comment: Did you follow a pattern when applying your paste? And did you apply it sparingly? How do you have the radiators configured? Which way are the fans blowing? Is the Corsair software managing the pump and fan speed? Or do you have a fan-speed controller?

Comment: @spikey_richie I didn't apply any thermal paste, there was already paste on the block. I've used air coolers before that come with with a paste already applied to the block. I assumed that was the same thing with water block. The radiator fans are  setup to push air over the radiator and out of the case. Yes, the Corsair software is managing pump and fan speed. Thanks.

Comment: You might be better off asking this in a specialist forum like overclockers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 3955wx pro and H115ixt pro 280, too.

1. Do you have setted Corsair ICUE correctly? I use set the pump to "extreme", than I setted the personalized curve of fan based on RMP.
2. than, I "hacked" the H115i xt pro 280! I mounted two Noctua industrial fan capable of 3000 RPM, here the results: idle, cpu 2% load, about 33°,  during Cinebench, 100% cpu load, I obtained 70°.